# Incongruence between model output shape and expected shape in custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I have an issue where upon initializing a Keras model, defining a custom loss function, and running model.compile, I receive an error suggesting that y_pred should be of shape (?,1), despite my output dimension clearly being larger than that.

So my network looks like the following:

```
action_space_size = 30
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
hidden_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation='gelu', kernel_initializer=GlorotNormal())(inputs)
hidden_layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation='gelu', kernel_initializer=GlorotNormal())(hidden_layer_1)
value = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='value')(hidden_layer_2)
mu = tf.keras.layers.Dense(action_space_size, activation=None, name='mu')(hidden_layer_2)
sigma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(action_space_size, activation='softplus', name='sigma')(hidden_layer_2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[value, mu, sigma])
```

And calling summary gives the following:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_56 (InputLayer)          [(None, 37)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_110 (Dense)              (None, 400)          15200       ['input_56[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 dense_111 (Dense)              (None, 400)          160400      ['dense_110[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 value (Dense)                  (None, 1)            401         ['dense_111[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 mu (Dense)                     (None, 30)           12030       ['dense_111[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 sigma (Dense)                  (None, 30)           12030       ['dense_111[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 200,061
Trainable params: 200,061
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Which all seems well and good for me.
But when I then define a custom loss function where the first line is the following:

```
def new_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    value_pred, mu_pred, sigma_pred = tf.unstack(y_pred, axis=-1, num=3)
```

And I run model.compile, I get the following error:

```
value_pred, mu_pred, sigma_pred = tf.unstack(y_pred, axis=-1,num = 3)

    ValueError: Dimension must be 3 but is 1 for '{{node loss_54/value_loss/unstack_1}} = Unpack[T=DT_FLOAT, axis=-1, num=3](value_55/BiasAdd)' with input shapes: [?,1].
```

Why does it think that my `y_pred` tensor should be of shape `(batch_size,1)`? That makes little sense to me.